# Using FindResource with a memory buffer

Tags: c++, winapi, embedded-resource

I'm have a memory buffer which contains a valid exe file image and I want to extract some resources from it.
 
For that I'm using the `FindResource` function, but the function expects a HMODULE and crashes when supplied a memory buffer with the exe. 
Is there a way to make it work with a memory buffer instead of writing the exe to a tempomary file, loading it using `LoadLibrary` and then doing the work needed?

Comment: You could parse the PE format and locate the resources yourself.

Comment: Now, this is undocumented and you shouldn't do it, but if your memory block is DWORD aligned (as it should) you should be able to get a valid resource-only `HMODULE` just by taking the taking the starting address and setting its low bit to 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm have a memory buffer which contains a valid file image

in which form ? i guess than in raw (as on disk). but you need 'mapped as image' memory for use FindResource. not hard map you raw image by self ( *if you want only access resource, but not execute it from memory*) example of code:

```
PVOID MapImage(PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER pvRawData, ULONG cbRawData)
{
    if (cbRawData < sizeof(IMAGE_DOS_HEADER))
    {
        return 0;
    }

    if (pvRawData->e_magic != IMAGE_DOS_SIGNATURE)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    ULONG e_lfanew = pvRawData->e_lfanew, s = e_lfanew + sizeof(IMAGE_NT_HEADERS);

    if (e_lfanew >= s || s > cbRawData)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS pinth = (PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS)RtlOffsetToPointer(pvRawData, e_lfanew);

    if (pinth->Signature != IMAGE_NT_SIGNATURE)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    ULONG SizeOfImage = pinth->OptionalHeader.SizeOfImage, SizeOfHeaders = pinth->OptionalHeader.SizeOfHeaders;

    s = e_lfanew + SizeOfHeaders;

    if (SizeOfHeaders > SizeOfImage || SizeOfHeaders >= s || s > cbRawData)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    s = FIELD_OFFSET(IMAGE_NT_HEADERS, OptionalHeader) + pinth->FileHeader.SizeOfOptionalHeader;

    if (s > SizeOfHeaders)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    ULONG NumberOfSections = pinth->FileHeader.NumberOfSections;

    PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER pish = (PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER)RtlOffsetToPointer(pinth, s);

    ULONG Size;

    if (NumberOfSections)
    {
        if (e_lfanew + s + NumberOfSections * sizeof(IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER) > SizeOfHeaders)
        {
            return 0;
        }

        do 
        {
            if (Size = min(pish->Misc.VirtualSize, pish->SizeOfRawData))
            {
                union {
                    ULONG VirtualAddress, PointerToRawData;
                };

                VirtualAddress = pish->VirtualAddress, s = VirtualAddress + Size;

                if (VirtualAddress > s || s > SizeOfImage)
                {
                    return 0;
                }

                PointerToRawData = pish->PointerToRawData, s = PointerToRawData + Size;

                if (PointerToRawData > s || s > cbRawData)
                {
                    return 0;
                }
            }

        } while (pish++, --NumberOfSections);
    }

    PVOID ImageBase = VirtualAlloc(0, SizeOfImage, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);

    if (!ImageBase)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    memcpy(ImageBase, pvRawData, SizeOfHeaders);

    if (NumberOfSections = pinth->FileHeader.NumberOfSections)
    {
        do 
        {
            --pish;

            if (Size = min(pish->Misc.VirtualSize, pish->SizeOfRawData))
            {
                memcpy(RtlOffsetToPointer(ImageBase, pish->VirtualAddress),
                    RtlOffsetToPointer(pvRawData, pish->PointerToRawData), Size);
            }

        } while (--NumberOfSections);

    }

    return ImageBase;
}

void Test(PVOID pvRawData, ULONG cbRawData, PCWSTR lpType, PCWSTR lpName)
{
    if (HMODULE ImageBase = (HMODULE)MapImage((PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER)pvRawData, cbRawData))
    {
        if (HRSRC hResInfo = FindResource(ImageBase, lpName, lpType))
        {
            if (HGLOBAL hg = LoadResource(ImageBase, hResInfo))
            {
                __nop();
            }
        }

        VirtualFree(ImageBase, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
    }
}
```

MapImage containing check for valid data sizes. however if you sure that (pvRawData, cbRawData) is 100% correct - you can skip this checks and simplify code

// i EDIT `Test` function based on @IInspectable comment - remove __try/__except - it not needed here

Comment: Why is there SEH in the `Test` function? None of the called functions are documented to raise Win32 exceptions.

Comment: @IInspectable - because if data of image is incorrect - `FindResource` can raise access violation. but if we sure that data correct (we have image as embedded resource, but not read it from disk or network)  - we can skip __try/__except. in MapImage i check only valid sizes for map. but for example what be if `pinth->OptionalHeader.DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_RESOURCE].VirtualAddress` incorrect ? exception in `FindResource`

Comment: @IInspectable - however you right - now i check - `FindResource` internal handle exception, so we can remove __try\__except block

Answer (score 0):

Your options:

1. Save to temporary file and load with `LoadLibraryEx`.
2. Parse the PE file and locate the resource yourself.
3. Replicate the necessary actions to load the module from memory in the manner of one of the various memory module libraries.